# iOS: Unable to update the frame of a view in a cell when loading the tableview

Tags: ios, swift, layout, frame, uitableview

I have a standard tableView with cells.

In theses cells, there's a view i need to change the frame position while scrolling.

I did a function updating the frame depending of its position  within the tableview (i'm using `convertRect(_:toView:)`)
When scrolling, It's working fine, i'm calling this function within the `UIScrollViewDelegate` function `scrollViewDidScroll(_)`.

My problem is to set the view's initial position while loading the cell.

To do so, I'm calling the same function i did in `tableView(_:willDisplayCellforRowAtIndexPath:)` to set the frame of the view when it's ready to display.

When i'm logging the view frame after the function, it has the expected values, but on the screen the view is at the wrong position, like the display hasn't refreshed.

I know changing a frame while loading views can be tricky and lead to such things, but i tried everything i can think of and find, no matter in which tableview/cell function i'm trying to update the view's frame, it doesn't change until i start scrolling.

For the record, i tried in :

- main controller `tableView(_:willDisplayCellforRowAtIndexPath:)`
- main controller `viewDidAppear()`
- cell `layoutSubviews()`
- cell `drawRect()`

I also tried with the constraints in autolayouts, but nothing related.

I'm sure I'm missing the right spot where to update the frame when loading the cell, but i can't figure it out.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the initial frames of UITableViewCell subivews in

> cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: It's too soon in this function, the frame of the cell isn't initialized yet

Comment: You can initialize whatever you want first, and then call tableView.reloadData(), and cellForRowAtIndexPath will be called again for every cell

Comment: No, It depends of the cell frame, which isn't set yet in tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:). Calling reloadData doesn't solve anything, but loading twice all the tableview, which is useless. In the best scenario, it shouldn't be necessary to do any reloading.